# Some questions on java multithreading,

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a set of questions regarding Java multithreading issues. Please provide me with as much help as you can.

**0)** Assume we have 2 banking accounts and we need to transfer money between them in a thread-safe way. 
i.e.

```
accountA.money += transferSum; 
accountB.money -= transferSum;
```

Two requirements exist:

1. no one should be able to see the intermediate results of the operation (i.e. one acount sum is increased, but others is not yet decreased)
2. reading access should not be blocked during the operation (i.e. old values of account sums should be shown during the operation goes on)

Can you suggest some ideas on this?

**1)** Assume 2 threads modify some class field via synchronized method or utilizing an explicit lock. Regardless of synchronization, there are no guarantee that this field will be visible to threads, that read it via NOT synchronized method. - **is it correct?**

**2)** How long a thread that is awoken by notify method can wait for a lock? Assume we have a code like this:

```
synchronized(lock) {  
    lock.notifyall();   
    //do some very-very long activity  
    lock.wait() //or the end of synchronized block  
}
```

Can we state that at least one thread will succeed and grab the lock? Can a signal be lost due to some timeout?

**3)** A quotation from Java Concurrency Book:

"Single-threaded executors also provide sufficient internal synchronization to guarantee that any memory writes made by tasks are visible to subsequent tasks; this means that objects can be safely confined to the "task thread" even though that thread may be replaced with another from time to time."

Does this mean that the only thread-safety issue that remains for a code being executed in single-threaded executor is data race and we can abandon the volatile variables and overlook all visibility issues? It looks like a universal way to solve a great part of concurrency issues.

**4)** All standard getters and setters are atomic. They need not to be synchronized if the field is marked as volatile. - **is it correct?**

**5)** The initiation of static fields and static blocks is accomplished by one thread and thus need not to be synchronized. - **is it correct?**

**6)** Why a thread needs to notify others if it leaves the lock with wait() method, but does not need to do this if it leaves the lock by exiting the synchronized block?

Comment: I like the fact that his question index starts from 0 and not from 1 :)

Comment: Quick note on 0) - this is a common requirement but is normally solved at a database level with transactions, not at an application level. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0: You can't.

Assuring an atomic update is easy: you synchronize on whatever object holds the bank accounts. But then you either block all readers (because they synchronize as well), or you can't guarantee what the reader will see.

BUT, in a large-scale system such as a banking system, locking on frequently-accessed objects is a bad idea, as it introduces waits into the system. In the specific case of changing two values, this might not be an issue: it will happen so fast that most accesses will be uncontended.

There are certainly ways to avoid such race conditions. Databases do a pretty good job for ba nk accounts (although ultimately they rely on contended access to the end of a transaction).

1) To the best of my knowledge, there are no guarantees other than those established by `synchronized` or `volatile`. If one thread makes a synchronized access and one thread does not, the unsynchronized access does not have a memory barrier. (if I'm wrong, I'm sure that I'll be corrected or at least downvoted)

2) To quote that JavaDoc: "The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object." If you decide to throw a sleep into that synchronized block, you'll be unhappy.

3) I'd have to read that quote several times to be sure, but I believe that "single-threaded executor" is the key phrase. If the executor is running only a single thread, then there is a strict happens-before relationship for all operations on that thread. It **does not** mean that other threads, running in other executors, can ignore synchronization.

4) No. `long` and `double` are not atomic (see the [JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Threads.doc.html#22244)). Use an `AtomicXXX` object if you want unsynchronized access to member variables.

5) No. I couldn't find an exact reference in the JVM spec, but section [2.17.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#24237) implies that multiple threads may initialize classes.

6) Because **all** threads wait until **one** thread does a notify. If you're in a synchronized block, and leave it with a wait and no notify, every thread will be waiting for a notification that will never happen.

Comment: Re 5), "Java Concurrency in Practice" states that class initialization (including static initialization blocks and `static final` members) is guarded by the JVM, so it is guaranteed to be thread safe. Nonfinal members aren't guarded, though.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not one to contradict Brian Goetz, but given the cautions about thread-safety in the JVM spec, (1) I'd like to see the exact quote, and (2) I wouldn't be surprised if there's a JVM that doesn't single-thread class initialization. It would certainly make the JVM implementation team's life easier if they did single-thread.

Comment: @parsifa, JVM does use the current loading thread to initialize the class and it uses locks to ensure thread safety. Single thread initialization would awfully dumb

Comment: @bestsss - perhaps it's a language issue, but "single-threading" an operation via locks is exactly what you're describing. And I trust that you are an active JDK developer, so you speak from a position of authority?

Comment: @parsifal, JCiP section 16.2.3: "The treatment of static fields with initializers (or fields whose value is initialized in a static initialization block) [...] offers additional thread-safety guarantees. Static initializers are run by the JVM at class initialization time, after class loading but before the class is used by any thread. Because the JVM acquires a lock during initialization [JLS 12.4.2] and this lock is acquired by each thread at least once to ensure that the class has been loaded, memory writes made during static initialization are automatically visible to all threads." contd.

Comment: "Thus statically initialized objects require no explicit synchronization either during construction or when being referenced. However, this applies only to the as-constructed stateif the object is mutable, synchronization is still required by both readers and writers to make subsequent modifications visible and to avoid data corruption."

Comment: @parsifal, single thread would imply one thread per VM similar to the finalizer or java2d disposer (sun.java2d.Disposer). Locking the class and/or the ClassLoader is fine grained synchronization compared to one-thread-per-VM. No, I am not a JVM developer, however I have not so shabby knowledge both on core classes and the C impl, I just do not develop it myself.

Comment: @Peter - OK. As I read that, it follows the JVM spec. A single class will not be initialized by multiple threads, but two classes that share mutable state must explicitly synchronize their changes to that state (ie, two classes that share a `HashMap`). IMO, such changes represent a misuse of static initializers, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

**0)** Is a difficult problem because you don't want intermediate results to be visible or to lock readers during the operation. To be honest I'm not sure it's possible at all, in order to ensure no thread sees intermediate results you need to block readers while doing both writes.

If you dont want intermediate results visible then you have to lock both back accounts before doing your writing. The best way to do this is to make sure you get and release the locks in the same order each time (otherwise you get a deadlock). E.G. get the lock on the lower account number first and then the greater.

**1)** Correct, all access must be via a lock/synchronized or use volatile.

**2)** Forever

**3)** Using a **Single Threaded** Executor means that as long as all access is doen by tasks run by that executor you dont need to worry about thread safety/visibilty.

**4)** Not sure what you mean by standard getters and setters but writes to most variable types (except double and long) are atomic and so don't need sync, just volatile for visibility. Try using the Atomic variants instead.

**5)** No, it is possible for two threads to try an init some static code, making naive implementations of Singleton unsafe.

**6)** Sync and Wait/Notify are two different but related mechanisms. Without wait/notify you'd have to spin lock (i.e. keep getting a lock and polling )on a object to get updates

Comment: 0 - it's possible, need state machine and cloned versions of the accounts + version control. However the main issue is what happens w/ the read data, since it can be inconsistent at any moment.

Comment: I guess my point was that if you don't want any locking and dont want any inconsistencies than it isn't possible.

Comment: you can possibly spin till succeed but in that case read/writes are times easier to implement and get it right

Answer (score 1):

5) The initiation of static fields and static blocks is accomplished by one thread and thus need not to be synchronized. - is it correct?

VM executes static initialization in a synchronized(clazz) block.

```
static class Foo {
    static {
        assert Thread.holdsLock(Foo.class); // true

        synchronized(Foo.class){  // redundant, already under the lock
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

0)  The only way I can see to do this to to store accountA and accountB in an object stored in an AtomicReference.  You then make a copy of the object, modify it, and update the reference if it is still the same as the original reference.

```
AtomicReference<Accounts> accountRef;

Accounts origRef;
Accounts newRef;
do {
   origRef = accountRef.get();
   // make a deep copy of origRef

   newRef.accountA.money += transferSum; 
   newRef.accountB.money -= transferSum; 
} while(accountRef.compareAndSet(origRef, newRef);
```